# Silverlight GridView and Combobox

Tags: silverlight, xaml, gridview, combobox, telerik

I have a combobox in a gridview in my silverlight application.

```
<Controls1:GridViewComboBoxColumn Header="Accomplishment Category" 
ItemsSource="{Binding AccomplishmentCategoryList}" 
DataMemberBinding="{Binding AccomplishmentCategoryValue}"  
SelectedValueMemberPath="{Binding AccomplishmentCategoryValue}">
</Controls1:GridViewComboBoxColumn>
```

I am able to get my grid to display the results for its own itemSource.

```
<Controls1:RadGridView x:Name="Accomplishments" Grid.Row="1" CanUserInsertRows="True" 
ShowInsertRow="True" CanUserDeleteRows="True" RowIndicatorVisibility="Visible" 
IsReadOnly="False" ItemsSource="{Binding AccomplishmentResults, Mode=TwoWay}">
```

The AccomplishmentResults collection binds perfectly. my issue is the combobox does not display anything until you actually click on the column that contains the combobox control. so that column looks empty, when you click on the column the results are displayed, when you click again you get the combobox that will show the items in that collection..if you select anything other than that column those values disappear and are empty again. if you select the row they remain empty..it is only when the column is selected that the values appear.

Answer (score 0):

By default ListView and DataGrid only displays text till the item is clicked and item becomes editable.

You will have to create Templated Column, that will always display combobox as declared in template.